# Number Formatting Varchar to currency

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers

I'm stuck with a column in `varchar(50)` here that I would like to have in currency format. Some examples of the AMOUNT column are:

```
-128,533.74 
-55,156.11
77,120.24
```

I just keep getting an error saying can't convert. What's the best way to handle this with the punctuation and sign?

Comment: you can `convert` to `money` like this `SELECT CONVERT(MONEY,'-55,156.11')`

Comment: If at all possible you should consider changing the datatype from varchar to a numeric datatype. When you are using the proper datatype this type of issue resolves itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the comma and then convert the value to a numeric data type:

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(50);
SET @Number = '-128,533.74';

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4),REPLACE(@Number,',',''))
```